# Ruby Builder conflict

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a small ruby app that has been working. I am now getting a conflict error with builder. It looks like I updated my gems and now it is conflicting. I have it set in the Gemfile to use v2.1.2. But that is not working either. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Gemfile

```
gem 'builder', '2.1.2'
```

Bundler output

```
$ bundle
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 

$ bundle show builder
/Users/covard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/builder-2.1.2
```

Conflict message

```
`raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.11, because rack-1.5.0 conflicts with rack (~> 1.4.0), builder-3.1.4 conflicts with builder (~> 3.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: some reading http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/5/besides-being-faster-what-else-is-new-in-bundler-1-1

Comment: sweet thanks for the link, I was wondering how to use the bundle cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what my problem was even though I had my Gemfile I wasn't using it. Since rails handles that automatically I didn't know I had to add a require to use it. After adding this to my ruby files it worked perfectly.

```
require "bundler/setup"
```